# Android ViewPager with Dynamic Content on Creation

Tags: android-layout

I have an activity that lists multiple records from a database stored in a data object that are presented in a TableView.  When the user taps a row, the object is passed to another activity which will display all of the details.  That activity uses a ViewPager to display the information on 5 pages using layout XML files in the instantiateItem method of my custom PagerAdapter class.  The ViewPager works fine but I need to be able to "refresh" the pages with the data from the passed object immediately but the views on the pages are not yet available in the onCreate method of the activity.  Is there some method to be able to accomplish this.